# conversion of java string into javascript string

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Iam new to jsp and trying to convert java string to jsp.the code ran when it is given inside js function but not through print statement

```
<%String ui = "df" ;%>
<script>function h(){alert('<%=ui%>');}</script>;
<%h%>
```

when invoked is running

```
<% String ui = "df" ;
out.println("<script>alert('<%=ui"+""+"%"+">');</script>");%>
```

not running through print statement

Comment: i didn't test it but i'm suggesting you to try this : 
<% String ui = "df" ;
out.println( " <script>alert("+ui+")</script>" ) ; %>

Comment: I tried it but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code outputs the following string:
`<script>alert('<%=ui%>');</script>`

What you want is JSP to interpret `ui`, so you should replace your code with:

```
out.println("<script>alert('" + ui + "');</script>");
```

or simply, outside of the scriptlet <% ... %> block:

```
<script>alert('<%=ui%>');</script>
```

Note that code above could cause issues, for example if `ui` string contains quotes. You should *escape* it, using for example apache commons, `StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(ui)`.